# Example of factorization with the Montgomery curve

Tags: elliptic-curve, factorization

I have programmed the elliptic curve method for integer factorization using Montgomery curves(the same idea as Lenstra's elliptic curve method, just changed a bit so it works with Montgomey curves). However, I haven't really been able to find any examples of numbers being factorized using the method, and I would really like to be able to test it on numbers I know should give a result, in order to check if it works as it should. So my question is, does anyone have an example of the method used on numbers, so that I can see whether my code gives the same output using the same numbers?

Comment: It's trivial to find numbers to test it on. Just multiply some appropriately sized primes together.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to factor the Mersenne number M(677) = 2^677-1 = 1943118631 * 531132717139346021081 * 978146583988637765536217 * P53 * P98. The P53 can be found by elliptic curve factorization with B1 = 9000000, B2 = 16000000, and lucky curve sigma = 8689346476060549. You might enjoy [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/04/27/modern-elliptic-curve-factorization-part-2/), which gives a solution to that factorization and also has a bunch of other prime-number stuff if you want to poke around.